# Start only one transition of an icon in a div with css

Tags: html, css

I set the color transition on hover of three icons. Those icons are in the same div and when I put the mouse on the div the transition of all the divs start. I would like that when I put the mouse on an icon in the div, only that transition starts and not the others. I thought I knew how to do it but I was wrong.

My code:

HTML:

```
<div id="icons">
<div id="logoquestion">
<a href="" target="_blank"><img src="Images/question-mark.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;"></a>
     </div>
<div id="logofbcol">
     <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="Images/logofacebookcolori.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;"></a>
     </div>
<div class="logoemailcol">
     <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="Images/logoemail.png" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;"></a>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#logoemailcol{
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -o-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -ms-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
}

#icons:hover > #logoemailcol{
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -o-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -ms-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
}

#logofbcol{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -o-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -ms-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
}

#icons:hover > #logofbcol{
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -o-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -ms-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
}

#logoquestion{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -o-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -ms-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
}

#icons:hover > #logoquestion{
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -o-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -ms-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing

```css
#icons:hover > #logofbcol
```

with

```css
#logofbcol:hover
```

for each of your divs.